# Changing column from nvarchar to int and converting data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a Users table that is used to hold data for a user's gender in nvarchar(6) format. I changed the software to use enums to indicate gender and thus wish to save data as an int.

0 = Male, 1 = Female.

I put each username and old nvarchar gender in a separate table and have converted the gender column in the original Users table to an int column. How can I set my query up to take all the users in my temp table and match them by user name to users in the Users table and then set the gender = 0 or 1 depending on if the old value is "Female" or "Male"?

**Users**
id **int** PK
Username **nvarchar**(50)
Gender **int**

**tempTable**
id **int** PK (Clusted Index w/no relation to the User's PK)
username **nvarchar**(50)
gender **nvarchar**(6)

I want to match users in `tempTable` by `username` to users in `Users` table by `Username` and update the `Users.Gender` value to either 0 or 1 based on `tempTable.gender` being either male or female.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
update a set gender = case b.Gender
                                when 'Male' then 0
                                when 'Female' then 1
                          end
from users a inner join
    tempTable b on b.Username = a.Username
```

This assumes every 'old' value is either Male or Female, and doesn't account for bad/missing data.